# How to instantiate more than one AsyncTask in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, classcastexception, swiperefreshlayout

I've been frustrated for two days with putting an AsyncTask in a SwipeRefreshLayout. I have read SwipeRefreshLayout and Async documnetation and I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Both serial and parallel I have tested (execute and executeOnexecutor) and none is working.
I've been googling a lot but apparently no one else has been dealing with same problem. What am I doing wrong? please help me!

I have an activity with a ListView in which I am trying to add a SwipeRefreshLayout. Without the swipe layout every thing goes well. But when I add the swipe, I get the below erroe when it's onRefresh() gets called.

Fatal error :

```
*.*.*.AllNewsListPageActivity$2 cannot be cast to *.*.*.AllNewsListPageActivity
java.lang.ClassCastException:*.*.AllNewsListPageActivity$2 cannot be cast to *.*.AllNewsListPageActivity
        at **.AllNewsListPageAsync.<init>(AllNewsListPageAsync.java:27)
        at **.AllNewsListPageActivity$2.onRefresh(AllNewsListPageActivity.java:86)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$1.onAnimationEnd(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:167)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView.onAnimationEnd(CircleImageView.java:107)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.finishAnimatingView(ViewGroup.java:5269)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2947)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14485)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13379)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13421)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14199)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14485)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13379)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13421)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14199)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14485)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:509)
```

what is this **$2** at the end of `AllNewsListPageActivity$2` ?!

Here is the code:

Activity.onCreate()

```
AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{this, listView});
    temp.execute();//executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_all_news_list_page_SwipeRefreshLayout);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{this, listView});
            temp.execute();//executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });
```

Async:

```
public class AllNewsListPageAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<NewsDetailObject>> {


AllNewsListPageActivity context;
ListView listView;
Object[] temp;
String sessionId;
public AllNewsListPageAsync(Object[] params){
    temp = params;
    context = (AllNewsListPageActivity) temp[0];
    listView = (ListView) temp[1];
    sessionId = ((Application9090)context.getApplicationContext()).getSessionId();
}

protected ArrayList<NewsDetailObject> doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    ArrayList<NewsDetailObject> newsList = NewsFeedProxy.getAllNewsDetailObjectList(100, sessionId);
    return newsList;
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsDetailObject> newsDetailObjectsList){
    super.onPostExecute(newsDetailObjectsList);
    context.newsListIds = ArrayHelper.extractIds(newsDetailObjectsList);

    ((ProgressBar) context.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_activity_all_news_list_page)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AllNewsListPageAdapter test;
    test = new AllNewsListPageAdapter(context, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textViewTitleNewsTitle , newsDetailObjectsList);

    listView.setAdapter(test);

    return;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks before.

Comment: `$2` refers to the 2nd page of your swipelayout

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the class cast exception?

Comment: It does, otherwise it would not be referred to in the error message. But I know not the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{this, listView});
        temp.execute();//executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }
});
```

inside `onRefresh` method pass reference of onRefreshListener class
change it to:

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{AllNewsListPageActivity.this, listView});
        temp.execute();//executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
 AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{this, listView});
```

to

```
 AllNewsListPageAsync temp = new AllNewsListPageAsync(new Object[]{AllNewsListPageActivity.this, listView});
```

Comment: Yep, this is because `this` refers to the anonymous class instance, not the parent.